# What's the differences between help and ? and ?? in R language

Tags: r

I want to find the instruction of a function of a R package, so I run `help('pkg::name')`. But I got the message saying 'no document for that'. I retried `??pkg:name` and it returned a very short instruction. When it came to `?pkg:name`, the full instructions showed up.
What are the differences between `?` and `??` and `help()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the help for "?":

```
> ?"?"
```

and the help for "??":

```
> ?"??"
```

in short, "?" finds the help for a single existing item, and "??" *searches* the help for some text. So "??random" searches for "random", and "?random" tries to find something called "random" (which doesn't exist so I get a message).

Comment: The doc pretty much says that `?` and `help` do the same thing, but yet the code of `?`, even not considering the support of `??` and binary `?` does more than just call the default `help()` (from what I remember!). I have never digged enough to identify those differences though.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper The `?` function, as revealed by `get("?")` also handles constructs like `class?data.frame` and also has a clause that contacts  the famous  oracle at Delphi. Really. I've not figured out how to trigger this yet though...

Comment: @spacedman:  Try `????something`.  One other point for Jie:  `?pkg::name` is equivalent to `help("name", "pkg")`, not `help("pkg::name")`.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` and `??` are short hands for `help()` and `help.search()` respectively.

For example:

```
help("lm")
help.search("linear models")
```

You use the first function when you know exactly what to search for, and the second function when you know approximately what to search for.